# Intersection of symmetric lines.

Tags: analytic-geometry

So I have to determine if these 2 symmetric lines intersect.

I converted them to parametric:

$$\begin{align}
-6+2t&=10+4s\\
-4+3t&=4-2s\\
-1+2t&=-1-4s
\end{align}$$

Now, I know I have to solve so I solved it and when t=4 and s=-2 the equation is equal, but how do I know where these 2 lines intersect? I know that they do, I just don't know where.

Comment: Plug $s$ or $t$ back to find the point

Comment: And multiply? that easy? So if my first vector equation is r=<-6,-4,-1>+t<2,3,2> they intersect at (8,12,8)?

Comment: So if my first vector equation is r=<-6,-4,-1>+t<2,3,2> they intersect at (8,12,8)?

Comment: Each equation corresponds to a coordinate $x,y$ or $z$. So plugging $s$ or $t$ back will yield a point on the line. As you've found the point where all three coordinates are equal and that point lays on the two lines, it's certainly their intersection. So the point is $<-6,-4,-1>+4<2,3,2>$.

Comment: Hey, tomorrow I have my Final exam in Calculus, do you mind if we chat? I have a couple questions.

Comment: I think there is a chat on math stackexchange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23971/discussion-between-alexey-burdin-and-julio).